# How do I prevent Pidgin from loading XMPP chat room history on join?

Tags: pidgin, xmpp

In Pidgin, when I join a chat room, it loads the chat room history.  iChat on the Mac has a preference in the Accounts section to set a variable amount of history to load, or disable loading history entirely.  How do I do the same thing in Pidgin?  Is there a preference somewhere that I've missed?  The object is to have the chat room start fresh each day, so I'd also be fine with disabling chat room history entirely on the server if that's possible.  But I didn't see that option either when I looked in Server Admin on the server.

I found [this list of XMPP room types](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#terms-rooms), and it looks like creating a Temporary Room might be the best way to do this, but I don't want to have to create the room manually every morning.  Right now I've got Pidgin set to auto-join the room when I log in; I want it to do that without loading history.

EDIT: The XMPP multi-user chat spec referenced above also contains a [section on managing history](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-managehistory).  And I got this to work by pulling up the XMPP Console plugin in Pidgin, copying the `<presence />` stanza it sent when I joined the room, closing the room, pasting the stanza into the console, adding the `<history />` element and sending it.  When I opened the room again, I had no history.  But it all came back the next time!

**So:** how do I get Pidgin to send the `<history />` stanza by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pidgin doesn't support that yet, AFAIK.  [There is support in libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/10986), so you could write a patch or a plugin for Pidgin to do this.